# I am getting a 404 not found axios error while sending a post request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I trying to send data by post request from react.js to express.js using axios but I am getting a 404 not found axios error.
here is the image of error q https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7ihV.png

here is my code
React.js at the client side

```
export default function Upload() {
   const [state, setState] = useState({
        title: "",
        desc: ""
    });
    const handleTextChange = (event) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        setState({...state, [event.target.name]:value});
    }
   
     const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const Data= {
            title: state.title,
            desc: state.desc
        };
        axios
        .post("http://localhost:5000/uploadData", Data)
        .catch(console.log);
     }
     return(
        <div>
            <h1>Upload your video</h1>

            <Stack gap={2}>
                <Form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formTitle">
                        <Form.Label>Title</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control type="text" name="title" />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formDesc">
                        <Form.Label>Description</Form.Label>
                        <Form.Control as="textarea" rows={3} name="desc"  onChange={handleTextChange} />
                    </Form.Group>
                    <Button variant="outline-primary" type="submit">submit</Button>
                    <Button variant="outline-light" type="reset">reset</Button>
                </Form>
            </Stack>
          </div>
    );
}
```

Express.js code at server side

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const router = express.Router();
onst app = express();
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

router.post("/uploadData", async (req, res) => {
  try{
    const newVideo = await Videos.create({title: req.body.title, desc: req.body.desc});
    res.send({newVideo});
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).send({error: err});

  }
});
const port = 5000;
app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server Listening on ${port}`);
});
```

can someone point out the error.

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or something but on server side in your code`express` might not be initialized due to this `onst app = express(); `

Answer (score 1):

You have several issues with your code. You don't seem to be dealing with your `axios.post` response anywhere. Update like so:

```js
axios.post("http://localhost:5000/uploadData", Data)
.then((response) => {
 // Handle response
 console.log(response.data);
})
.catch(error => {
   console.log(error)
})
```

Then on your server-side you have typo in `onst app = express();` and you don't need the `router` if you are not going use a modular pattern i.e all your code in the same file so chaining your HTTP methods to `app` will be suffice. You haven't mounted `router` using `app.use()` so unless you have some other code that I can't see here I don't even think your app is able to respond to requests on `/uploadData`. Modify your code like so:

```js
const app = express(); //< Change to 'const' instead on 'onst'
//...
//...
app.post("/uploadData", async (req, res) => { //< Change to app.post
  try{
    const newVideo = await Videos.create({title: req.body.title, desc: req.body.desc});
    res.status(201).json({  //< Send a json response with the newVideo
       newVideo
    });
  } catch(err) {
    res.status(400).json({  //< Send a json response with error
       error: err
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: does not changes anything still the same error

Comment: Ok to help with debugging. 1. Is your react front-end and your back-end on the same port 5000? 2. Can you restart your server-side and make sure it says `Server Listening on 5000`. 3. In your `app.post("/uploadData` route can you `console.log(req.body)` as the first statement in the the `try` block.  What does it say? 4. Is a new video being added to your database or not?

Comment: the server is listening on 500 and I have changed `router.post` to `app.post` at server side and also handling response with `axios.post`, but now I am getting axios error 400 bad request, I think the problem is with the data format that I am passing in `axios.post(), at client side, can you please check.

Comment: What is the output if you `console.log(req.body)` inside the `app.post`? Is there data in there? That will tell you if you are sending it properly and it's been parsed. If `req.body` doesn't have your `title` or `desc` then it's not being sent by axios.

Comment: no there is no data at the end point I suppose

Comment: Yes, you need to debug on your client-side to see how you are setting the `Data` object.

Comment: can you please point out where did I made a mistake while creating the Data object

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar with your implementation.  When I've used React I use classes so `export default class Upload extends React.Component { state = { title: '',  } handleChange = e=> { this.setState({ title: e.target.value }); }  handleSubmit = ev=> { ev.preventDefault(); const data= { title: this.state.title };`